# How to determine max length of a certain array column?

Tags: php, arrays, string

The array looks like this:

```
array(
  array(5, true, 'Foo'),
  array(8, true, 'Bar'),
  array(8, true, 'FooBar'),
)
```

Can I determine the longest string length of the 3rd column, without having to iterate over the array?

In my example the longest string would be "FooBar" - 6 chars.

If the inner array had only the string element, I could do `max(array_map('strlen', $arr))`, but it has 3 items...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `array_map('array_pop', $arr)` to the mix:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  array(5, true, 'Foo'),
  array(8, true, 'Bar'),
  array(8, true, 'FooBarss')
);

print_r(max(array_map('strlen', array_map('array_pop', $arr))));

?>
```

http://codepad.org/tRzHoy7Z

Gives `8` (after I added the two `ss` to check). [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) takes the last array element off and returns it, use [`array_shift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get the first.

Answer (score 2):

First I'm pretty sure that the max function iterates over the whole array. But if you're fine with using it then you can define your own comparison function and pass it.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if (strlen($a[2]) == strlen($b[2])))
        return 0;
    return (strlen($a[2]) < strlen($b[2])) ? -1 : 1;
}

max(array_map('cmp', $arr))
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the second line. And at least according to this test on codepad, [this doesn't work](http://codepad.org/Tr2nXf8M).

Answer (score 0):

Simply sorting the array of arrays then picking the first positioned row involves extra/unnecessary algorithmic sorting (specifically for non-longest rows) and also may give misleading results if there is a tie for longest.

I recommend accommodating the possibility of multiple longest strings and only traversing the input array one time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jd9jN))

```
$array = [
  [5, true, 'FooBar'],
  [8, true, 'Bar'],
  [18, true, 'IsTied'],
];

$result = [];
$longest = 0;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $len = strlen($row[2]);
    if ($len >= $longest) {
        $longest = $len;
        $result[$len][] = $row;
    }
}
var_export($result[$longest] ?? []);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 5,
    1 => true,
    2 => 'FooBar',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 18,
    1 => true,
    2 => 'IsTied',
  ),
)
```

That said, if you just want to see the longest length and don't care where it came from, then you can use this:

```
var_export(max(array_map('strlen', array_column($array, 2))));
```